# Pandas adding NA changes column from float to object

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I have a dataframe with a column that is of type float64. Then when I run the following it converts to object, which ends up messing with a downstream calculation where this is the denominator and there are some 0s:

```
df.loc[some criteria,'my_column'] = pd.NA
```

After this statement, my column is now of type object. Can someone explain why that is, and how to correct this? I'd rather do it right the first time rather than adding this to the end:

```
df['my_column'] = df['my_column'].astype(float)
```

Thanks.

Comment: [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#experimental-na-scalar-to-denote-missing-values) "Currently, pandas does not yet use those data types by default (when creating a DataFrame or Series, or when reading in data), so you need to specify the dtype explicitly. An easy way to convert to those dtypes is explained [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#missing-data-na-conversion)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pandas, you can use NA or np.nan to represent missing values. np.nan casts it to float which is what you want and what the documentation states it as. NA casts the column as string and is best used for  dtype string columns.

```
df.loc[some criteria,'my_column'] = np.nan
```

Comment: Yep this works, still a bit odd that pd.NA behaves that way, but I'll change to this thanks :)